# Difference between "far too much" and "far to much"?

Tags: to-infinitive

I was writing a sentence recently and had to Google this because I didn't know if I should have used "to much" or "too much".

sentence:

> Too much of an undertaking at the moment, and far too much code that needs to be rewritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Too much" and "far too much" are both correct the second phrase being stronger than the first.

"To much" and "far to much" are wrong as phrases.

You would only see "to much" in a sentence where "to" is used in the sense of direction as in:

"I didn't pay attention to much of his speach"

Comment: thanks. is the "sense of direction" rule the only one?

Answer (score 1):

***far*** is just an optional "intensifier" for ***too*** followed by an adjective. Note that ***too much, too many, too few*** are just "quantity-based" expressions, but more or less *any* "gradable" adjective can be modified using ***too*** to mean ***excessively***. So your question could be described as ***too basic***, and my comment could be ***too dismissive***, for example. It certainly wouldn't make any sense at all to replace ***too*** with ***to*** in any such context.

<sub>yet another community wiki, converted from a FumbleFingers comment</sub>